# Overflow Error 6 with the following Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The following code will format my template correctly the way I want.  However, in the event the template is empty and a user hits the prep upload button on the sheet, I will receive an Overflow Error 6.  Is there any way to remove what is causing this error?

```
    Sub PrepForUpload()

Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

For Each cel In rng

    If cel.Value = "" Then

        If cel.Offset(, 2).Value = "" Then
            cel.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    End If

    Next cel

Dim rowNumber As Integer
With Sheets("Initiatives")

If Len(.Cells(2, 1)) = 0 Then

rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1

Else: rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

End If

.Rows(rowNumber & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear

End With


End Sub
```

Debug points to the following line as the issue:

```
rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

Thanks

Ryan

Comment: Why are you calling `end` twice?

Comment: It shouldn't be called twice, however even when removed it still produces an overflow.  I am not sure how to figure out a way to code for an empty template without changing my entire code.

Comment: I deleted my original reply. It is not entirely clear to me what you are attempting to do with the line: rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1 => end(xlDown).row is like doing ctrl+arrow down. Why would you call it twice? I can upload new code if you need it.

Comment: Integer has an upper limit of about 32000.  You have more rows than that, so you should use Long instead for rowNumber.

Comment: Kim, the end result of the template is uploaded into Access.  If the List box within the cells below populated dated are imported, it will blow up the access database.  The line is meant to delete content below the populated data, including the listbox format

Comment: I have been trapped by this as well, unless I put "Break on All Errors" in the debugging options, the program did not stopped where the error occured !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting an overflow because `Integer` in VBA is a 16 bit signed number (max value of 32767).  Regardless of the version of excel, you have a minimum of  65535 rows and most likely more if you are using the XLSX file format.  You need to change `rowNumber` to a `Long`

And you also have to code around the blank worksheet scenerio.  When you call this line:

```
rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1
```

and the worksheet is blank, `.End(xlDown)` will return the last possible row in the worksheet, which in the case of Excel 2010 (and Excel 2007) is 1048576.  Once you change `rowNumber` to a `Long` you will no longer get the overflow error, but you will run into a problem with this line:

```
.Rows(rowNumber & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear
```

This is because you are trying to select a range (row 1048577) that does not exist (hence the type mismatch).  You need to add a line of code to work around this scenario.  Either check initially for a blank worksheet, or check for row > 1048576.

The simplest thing to do is to just add a line to check this:

```
If rowNumber <= 1048576 Then
    .Rows(rowNumber & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `rowNumber` to `Long` then add `1&` or use `CLng` to get rid of the 'type-mismatch` error.

```
rowNumber = CLng(.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1)
```

or

```
rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1&
```

Comment: Amiss, this didn't produce any results. Debugger still points to the following after the mismatch error: ".Rows(rowNumber & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear"  This is driving me nuts!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us what your data looks like in column A? You can also try this code, which test for the number of lines before attempting to get the row number

```
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1)) <= 1 Then
    MsgBox "No lines"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set rng = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

For Each cel In rng

    If Len(cel.Value) = 0 Then

        If Len(cel.Offset(, 2).Value) = 0 Then cel.EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Next cel

Dim rowNumber As Long

With Sheets("Initiatives")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1)) <= 1 Then
        MsgBox "No lines in sheet Initiative"
        Exit Sub
    End If


If Len(.Cells(2, 1)) = 0 Then

    rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row + 1

    Else: rowNumber = .Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1

End If

.Rows(rowNumber & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear

End With
```