# VBA Overflow error after office 2007 to 2010 update

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have a VBA macro that worked correctly in Excel 2007 but after updating to 2010 it throws errors. The Macro basically copies raw data from one sheet to multiple sheets. The error being thrown is error 6: Overflow. The line that is throwing the error is Dim

```
y As Integer
y = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

I initially thought ok ill change it to long and it will kill the overflow error. Well i guess it killed the error but it also output very wrong results and then relized that the overflow error doesnt even make sense... there is only 973 rows.

I then thought ok maybe ill try this instead

```
Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Select
```

Now it throws "Run-time error '1004' method 'range' of object '_global' failed" on the line after.

below is a portion of the full code. **I am usure of how it could even be a overflow error? Any help is appreciated.**

```
Dim y As Integer
'y = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
y = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("B1:U" & y).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Yellow Suppliers").Select
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("C:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("P:Q").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 2.14
Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 43.43
Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 12.14
Columns("D:O").ColumnWidth = 8
Columns("P").ColumnWidth = 10.14

Rows("1").RowHeight = 15
Rows("2:" & y).RowHeight = 30

Range("B3:B22").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: Are you sure `y` evaluates to 973?

Comment: No im not but thats how many rows are in column A. I cant check what it evaulates to becasue the overflow error happens on the line that is setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of any `Select` or `Selection` in your code.  Also, confirm that `y` indeed does evaluate to the expected value of `973`.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim rngY as Range '## a variable to calculate the size of rows used in Column A'
Dim y As Integer

With Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set rng = .Range("A2").Resize( _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")))
End With
    y = rngY(rngY.Rows.Count).Row

    Range("B1:U" & y).Copy Destination:= _
        Sheets("Yellow Suppliers").Range("B2")

    Columns("C:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("P:Q").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 2.14
    Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 43.43
    Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 12.14
    Columns("D:O").ColumnWidth = 8
    Columns("P").ColumnWidth = 10.14

    Rows("1").RowHeight = 15
    Rows("2:" & y).RowHeight = 30

    Range("B3:B22").Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I Was not the originiator of the code, Select is used hundreds of times throughout the entire macro. Is there a reason not to use it? And i am unsure of how to evaluate y since the overflow error happens when it is set.

Comment: The line before you set that variable `y`, do this: `Debug.Print Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` and see what comes up in the Immediate window.

Comment: To the other question, yes, `Select` is really clunky, and 99.9% of the time it is unnecessary. It also makes your code less legible than if you avoid it, or example, your first copy/paste operation requires 5 lines of code, compared to the 1 line that it can be revised to.  [Here](http://www.businessprogrammer.com/201105/power-excel-vba-secret-avoid-using-select/) is a brief overview. If you have the time to revise your macro, it might not be terribly difficult, and will ultimately give you better code that will be easier to modify in the future.

Comment: No immediate window pops up and it proceedes past it to the error.

Comment: Please use F8 to step through the code. If necessary put a breakpoint on the `Debug.Print...` statement. The `Immediate` window is part of the VBE, it's not something that will "pop up" :)  Or, you could `MsgBox Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row` if you want a popup.

Comment: oH WOW it came up with 1048576. im completely not sure how or why it is pulling that much when its not there?

Comment: Thanks for all your help David! When i manually 'Ctrl' + 'Down' i do it multiple times and i reach the end of the data. If i do it one more time it jumps from line 973 to 1048576. Is there a way i can just make it not do the last 'Ctrl" + 'Down' ?

Comment: In the first answer here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624454/overflow-error-6-with-the-following-excel-2010-vba] it seems as if it thinks the worksheet is blank? im unsure of how 'Ctrl' + 'Down' exactly works since it is making me press is multiple times then it is selecting blank rows.

Comment: 1048576 is the last allowable row in Excel 2007+, so perhaps Column A is blank? What is the last cell with values in Column A, is it A973? or some other cell?

Comment: its A973, All cells in column A are filled upto A973. After A973 all cels and rows are blank.

Comment: OK, If there are no blanks between A2 and A973, see revised answer. I think that should work.

Comment: Dave im sorry upon further inspection there are a couple breaks :O! it came back with no errors but did not output correctly im assuming becasue of the blanks.

Comment: well yes I said before that this method works **if there are no blanks**. There seems to be a problem with your file, which is not correctly interpreting the last row. If you can upload your file to Google Docs, or email me (dzemens at Gmail) I can try to see what's causing that, and fix it).

Comment: Well i unfortunately can't send you the file but thanks for the help! I have altered it so there are no blanks in the row but i recieve "Run time error '1004' application defined or object defined error" on this line `Set rng = .Range("A2").Resize( _ Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")))`

Answer (score 0):

Integers in VBA are 16 bit signed numbers which means that the largest value they can take is 32767. There can be many more rows in a spreadsheet than that in the new Excel versions.

You need to use a long rather than an integer. A long is a 32 bit signed; plenty big enough.

So change `Dim y As Integer` to `Dim y as Long`

In fact I'm suprised it worked in Excel 2003 as that, if my memory is correct, has 65536 rows. But try my suggestion anyway as your code is definitely incorrect.