# WorksheetFunction.CountA - not working post upgrade to Office 2010

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

The following piece of code works in Excel prior to 2010:

```
myRange = Range("A:A")
NumRows = Application.CountA(myRange)
```

There are 38 cells containing text/values in column A. When the code is run in Excel 2007, NumRows correctly evaluates to 38, however, it (wrongly) evaluates to 65,536 in Excel 2010.

Entering the `CountA` function in-cell works OK in both versions.

Similar thread is [question 16696891](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696891/vba-overflow-error-after-office-2007-to-2010-update), but there was no answer and the suggestions were, I think, red herrings...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, because I cannot get your code to work as written.  Two things seem evident:

1. It appears you are relying on VBA to determine variable types and modify accordingly. This can get confusing if you are not careful, because VBA may assign a variable type you did not intend.  In your code, a type of `Range` should be assigned to `myRange`. Since a `Range` type is an object in VBA it needs to be `Set`, like this: `Set myRange = Range("A:A")`
2. Your use of the worksheet function `CountA()` should be called with `.WorksheetFunction`

If you are not doing it already, consider using the Option Explicit option at the top of your module, and typing your variables with `Dim` statements, as I have done below.

The following code works for me in 2010. Hopefully it works for you too:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim NumRows As Integer

Set myRange = Range("A:A")
NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Hi

Thanks both. Sorry, should have made it clear - the range is set using the Set keyword. Actually you don't need `.WorksheetFunction`, in fact `Application.CountA` should work on its own.

On the PC in question, `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))` shows 65,536 even though only 38 cells contain anything. I cannot replicate on my own desk. I thought it might be some sort of issue with upgrade from one version of office to another. The "new" PC has Office 2010 on Windows 7, and was upgraded from Office 2007 on Windows 2003.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the specific spreadsheet.  Try selecting all of the "empty" cells, deleting them, and saving.  If that does not result in the expected "38" result, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3):

This answer from another forum solved the problem.

(substitute your own range for the "I:I" shown here)

Re: CountA not working in VBA

```
Should be:

Nonblank = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("I:I"))

You have to refer to ranges in the vba format, not the in-excel format.
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim NumRows As Integer

    Set myRange = Range("A:A")
    NumRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange)

    MsgBox NumRows
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a change in how Application.COUNTA works in VB7 vs VB6.  I tried the following in both versions of VB.

```
   ReDim allData(0 To 1, 0 To 15)
   Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(allData)
```

In VB6 this returns 0.

Inn VB7 it returns 32

Looks like VB7 doesn't consider COUNTA to be COUNTA anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It may be obvious but, by stating the Range and not including which workbook or worksheet then it may be trying to CountA() on a different sheet entirely.
I find to fully address these things saves a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

How many Sheets do you have in the WorkBook?
Do your macro trigger when you open the WorkBook or from other WorkSheet (in the same WorkBook)?

I got some wrong results using WorksheetFunction.countA() when the referenced range is located in a different Sheet than the ActiveSheet, I suggest to select the Sheet that contains the data you are looking for first then proceed with the WorksheetFunction.countA()