# EXCEL VBA - how to pass # of filled cells inside a custom range, into the "i" variable using Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to assign a number to the "i" variable.
This # should be the number of filled cells inside the `Worksheets("Offset").Range("AN20:AN3000")`

Yes - "Offset" is in this case the name of the sheet.
Here is what I exactly need.
Inside aforementioned range there is 171 filled cells, and that number I need to assign to the "i" variable.
Preferably, I'd like to achieve that using `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA`

This is what I've managed to code myself

```
Sub celebrities_height_into_array()

   ' declare an array to hold celebrities height
   Dim height_array() As Integer
   Dim height_range As Range
   Dim i As Integer

   Set height_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offset").Range("AN20:AN3000")
   ' I keep celebrities height in this range, in centimeters.
   i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(height_range))

End Sub
```

Later I'm going to load all heights into the array.
[This is what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890571/excel-vba-worksheetfunction-counta-not-working-post-upgrade-to-office-2010) I've read about using WorksheetFunction.CountA

This is how my sheet looks like.
[image]

And here is the end of the Range.
[image]

Comment: Since `height_range` is defined and `Set` as `Range`,  change `i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(height_range))` to `i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(height_range)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is the extra `Range(`

Try the following code. It should work.

```
Sub celebrities_height_into_array()

   ' declare an array to hold celebrities height
   Dim height_array() As Integer
   Dim height_range As Range
   Dim i As Integer

   Set height_range = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Offset").Range("AN20:AN3000")
   ' I keep celebrities height in this range, in centimeters.
   i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(height_range)

End Sub
```

height_range is already defined as a range.